# Persisting entity with relation and form data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the AppBundle\Entity\Comments entity which I want to persist to the database when the user fill the form I can't find information exactly how to save the form data to the database:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Comments")
 */

class Comments
{
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;

        /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Employer")
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        */
        private $employer;

        /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        */
        private $company;

        /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Commenttypes")
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="comment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        */
        private $comment;

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="date")
        */
        private $from_date;

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="date")
        */
        private $to_date;
?>
```

Here is the Form Type:

```
<?
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class WorkerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('comment', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\CommentTypes',
                'label' => 'Comment:'
                ))
            ->add('from_date', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType', array(
                'label'  => 'From date:',
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                'attr'   => [ 'class' => 'datepicker' ]
                ))
            ->add('to_date', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType', array(
                'label'  => 'To date:',
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                'attr'   => [ 'class' => 'datepicker' ]
                ))
            ->add('submit', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType', array(
                'label'  => 'Submit',
                'attr'   => [ 'class' => 'buttonColor' ]
                ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
                $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Comments',
        ));
        }
}
?>
```

So by now, I'm receiving the data for the fields $from_date and $to_date and $comment (the ID of the comment from the dropdown) from the Form, what I need to to in my controller in order to persist the comment object to the database. Here is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Comments;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\WorkerType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Worker extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/worker/{id}", name="worker")
     */
    public function indexAction($id, Request $request)
    {       

        $comment = new Comments();

        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\Type\WorkerType', $comment);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {          

        {{{{ CODE HERE }}}}

        }

        return $this->render('default/worker.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

I exactly want to know what I need to do to persist the comment object if the form is valid, I'm trying with this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
$comment->setEmployer($id);
$comment->setCompany($this->getUser());
$comment->setComment($form->get('comment')->getData());
$comment->setfrom_date($form->get('from_date')->getData());
$comment->setto_date($form->get('to_date')->getData());
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Comments::setEmployer() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Employer, string given, called in /home1/rabotnici/src/AppBundle/Controller/Worker.php on line 42 and defined
```

Comment: Have you given any of this code a try?  When you submit the form and tie it to the `Comments` entity, the submitted form values will already be set in that `$comment` variable after you call `handleRequest()`.  You can do check the entity yourself to confirm this.

As for the current logged in user, you can use `$this->getUser();` in your controller.

I would also look at auto-generating your entities with Doctrine, or changing your variable names to $camelCase, such as `$fromDate` and `$toDate`.

Comment: I don't know where the `setEmployer` call came from, but you don't need to explicitly call the last three `set*` calls because your entity is already tied to the form submission.  Have you tried dumping out data and debugging to see what is actually in your entity after you submit?

Comment: As for the employer, you will need to retrieve an employer entity - but what is that based on?  Is it the current user's employer?  Will it be an employer retrieved from the URL or the form somehow?  Right now you're trying to pass it an id when it needs the whole object.

Comment: It's employer ID and I have it in $id variable as integer.

Comment: In that case you would need to do `$employer = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->get('AppBundle:Employer')->find($id);` and then `$comment->setEmployer($employer);`

Comment: It's working right now!!! Thank you very much! Do I need to check the ID everytime with $employer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Employer')->find($id); because I know its exist?

Comment: It depends.  You need to call that to retrieve the Employer object so that you can set it in your entity.  If you aren't positive that `$id` will always point to a valid Employer, you can check for it first and throw an exception if it does not exist.